# How can I define a multiple-record ID variable for a Cox model in R?

Tags: r, stata, cox-model, reproducible-research

I'm reproducing and translating data from an old Stata file into R for future expansion and analysis. The original data uses a Cox proportional hazard model with `stset` + `stcox`. Running Cox models in R is trivial with `survival::coxph`. However, the models in Stata define a multiple-record ID variable for the time series, and R seems to not be able to do the same.

Here's some example data. Running a model in Stata *without* defining an id variable is trivial:

```
import delimited "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrewheiss/c60cb1c9e55aaf42585f/raw/9c5568d7af43c9cf523cf72db2591e80b466b69a/df.csv", clear
stset years_since_event fail
stcox x1 x2, nohr
```

This produces these results:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          _t |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          x1 |   .1963139   .0375578     5.23   0.000      .122702    .2699259
          x2 |  -.5599549   .0642704    -8.71   0.000    -.6859225   -.4339872
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can produce the same results in R with `survival::coxph`:

```
library(survival)
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrewheiss/c60cb1c9e55aaf42585f/raw/9c5568d7af43c9cf523cf72db2591e80b466b69a/df.csv", na=".")
model1 <- coxph(Surv(years_since_event, fail) ~ x1 + x2, data=df, ties="breslow")  # Breslow because Stata
summary(model1)
```

Results:

```
       coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
x1  0.19631   1.21691  0.03756  5.227 1.72e-07 ***
x2 -0.55995   0.57123  0.06427 -8.712  < 2e-16 ***
```

In Stata, I can define a multiple-record ID variable for the time series by appending `id(name)` to `stset`, yielding results that are fairly substantially different from the first model, like so:

```
stset years_since_event fail, id(name)
stcox x1 x2, nohr
```

Results:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          _t |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          x1 |   .1584929   .0438302     3.62   0.000     .0725874    .2443984
          x2 |  -.3068401     .06471    -4.74   0.000    -.4336694   -.1800108
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, I have not found a way to define a multiple-record ID variable in R—there are no obvious arguments to adjust in either `coxph()` or `Surv()`.

So, is there a way reproduce the `stset years_since_event fail, id(name)` Stata command in R using `survival::coxph`?

UPDATE: Following Terry Therneau's answer, the way to fix this is to explicitly add a variable indicating the start time. Stata does this behind the scenes when you include `id(name)`, while R does not.

Here's what that looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(start_time = 0:(n() - 1))
head(df)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
# Groups: name [3]
# 
#          name years_since_event  fail       x1    x2 start_time
#         (chr)             (int) (int)    (dbl) (int)      (int)
# 1 Afghanistan                 1     0 17.07171     6          0
# 2 Afghanistan                 2     1 17.10008     5          1
# 3     Albania                 1     1 14.93779     1          0
# 4     Algeria                 1     0 17.23435     2          0
# 5     Algeria                 2     0 17.24892     2          1
# 6     Algeria                 3     0 17.26365     2          2

model2 <- coxph(Surv(start_time, years_since_event, fail) ~ x1 + x2, 
                data=df, ties="breslow") 
summary(model2)

#        coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
# x1  0.15849   1.17174  0.04383  3.616 0.000299 ***
# x2 -0.30684   0.73577  0.06471 -4.742 2.12e-06 ***
```

Comment: This can be done in R with the following formula:  `survObject ~ covar + cluster(id)` for the `coxph` function.

Comment: That clusters the standard errors by the id, but it doesn't affect the coefficients. See https://gist.github.com/6430d4d65e69109c03de

Comment: Ah. I'm not terribly familiar with exactly what Stata is doing. I think there is a good chance that it is fitting a frailty model. This can be fit in R, see `?frailty` in the survival package. Perhaps unfortunately, you have a few choices of the distribution of the frailty terms, so it might be worth checking exactly what Stata is doing.

Comment: It doesn't look like frailty or any sort of mixed effects—it looks like Stata is trying to do some sort of panel correction or something (http://www.stata.com/manuals13/ststset.pdf)

Comment: Where exactly is that shown? Stata certainly fits frailty models (see http://www.stata.com/manuals13/ststcox.pdf on page 30). But this particular manual does not seem to say what calls actually fit the frailty model.

Comment: On page 26 of that manual it shows how to call it—you add `shared(var)` as a term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Stata has implemented a variant of the counting process style of survival model, which uses (time1, time2, status) in R.  See chapter 3.7 of Therneau and Grambsch (Springer 2000) for an explanation of how this works.  The start,stop form is much more flexible, and appears to be what the enter/exit variables do in Stata.  If you use "id" then it builds the data set for you.  In R you need to create it yourself.

Comment: Welcome to CV! We hope you'll stay around & answer more questions from time to time.

Comment: Perfect! This fixes it. I've included an example of this in the original question.

Comment: Please consider registering your account.